# Permuting Entries in main Diagonal

Tags: algorithm, matrix, permutation

If i have 8*8 matrix. Having the following values

[image]

Want it to permute like following

[image]

Such that diagonal is divided into two part Top and Bottom. First entry `1` is filled at first location of Bottom part. Second entry `2` is placed at first location of top part and upto so on.

I want to extend this idea to other diagonals of matrix.

`for(int row = 0; row < dimension; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < dimension; col++){
            if(row == col){
                    // Do something to this cell.
                }
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the most straight-forward solution is to first save the diagonal values into additional array and then copy its elements in cycle into their position.

Possible solution in C:

```
int top = 0; // Index where the top part currently is
int bottom = SIZE/2; // Index where the bottom part currently is
int diagonal[SIZE]; // Additional array, which stores the diagonal elements

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    diagonal[i] = matrix[i][i]; // Fill the additional array with diagonal elements

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    if(i%2 == 0) // put it to lower part
    {
        matrix[bottom][bottom] = diagonal[i];
        bottom++; // Update the bottom index
    }

    else // put it to upper part
    {
        matrix[top][top] = diagonal[i];
        top++; // Update the top index
    }
}
```

Note, that `SIZE` has to be even number, in order to make it work like you described.

Comment: can't we make it to work on odd size of diagonal such as 7 or some other

Comment: Sure we can. But how do you want the matrix to look, for SIZE=7?

Comment: i want to do same for all diagonals of this matrix. Diagonal may be wrong term to use but i mean to say other diagonal paths of this matrix. I hope you understand my question

Comment: Which element you want to be in the middle then?

Comment: in odd case there will be one less element in bottom part. and will start filling at same pattern, first item to bottom part first location and second item at first location of top part and so on

Comment: Well I think that the solution is pretty straight-forward. I am not going to write the all code for you, as this is clearly your homework. You should be able to write the case for odd size with the code I provided for the evem case. Start writing and let me know when you run into a trouble.